# pushing array of string with variables to an array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Could someone help me on below code? How do I push an array with variables?

```
function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {
  var array = []
  var i;
  var m = ms[i];
  var it = its[i];
  var string = "`${m}` plays `${it}`";

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array.push(string)
  }

  return array
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is your intention to put the value of m and it into the string?

Comment: There's no `ms`, there's no `its`, `i` is `undefined`, `string = ...` is only executed once, and why the magic number `4`?

Comment: It looks like you've posted pseudocode. Have you tried to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you did should be placed inside the `for` loop. Like this:

```
function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments){
    var array = [];
    for(var i=0; i<musicians.length; i++){
        var m = musicians[i];
        var it = instruments[i];
        var string = `${m} plays ${it}`;
        array.push(string);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Also note the syntax for the template literal: the whole string is delimited by backticks, and you should not have those double quotes.

Instead of iteration to 4, use the actual length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments){
    var array = []
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        var m = ms[i];
        var it = its[i];
        var string = "`${m}` plays `${it}`";
        array.push(string)
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21989160)

Answer (score 0):

yes It is pseudo-code and It's actually something like this;

```js
var ms = ["a a", "b b", "c c"];
var its = ["d d", "e e", "f f"];
function funct(ms, its){
    var array = []
    var i =0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        var m = ms[i];
        var it = its[i];
        var string = "${m} plays ${it}";
        array.push(string)
    }
    return array
}
```